Was Tom Riddle the first Parselmouth to attend Hogwarts after Salazar Slytherin? Did none of his descendants (like the Gaunt family) attend Hogwarts?
In Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Tom Riddle told Harry that they are the only two Parselmouths to come to Hogwarts since Salazar Slytherin himself.

There are strange likenesses between us, after all. Even you must have noticed. Both half-bloods, orphans, raised by Muggles. Probably the only two Parselmouths to come to Hogwarts since the great Slytherin himself We even look something alike... but after all, it was merely a lucky chance that saved you from me.

As we know all members of Gaunt family were Parselmouths and they lived in Little Hangleton (England). Did none of them go to Hogwarts or was Tom Riddle just exaggerating?

@Turamarth it's possible the Gaunts attended Hogwarts but did not open the Chamber, they're not mutually exclusive actions.

"Probably the only two..." for what it's worth. Maybe he was just wrong. "Probably" isn't definitive.
